# How to run Apollo Graphql Prisma migrate deploy in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, apollo-server, prisma

Normally duration development I run

```
yarn prisma migrate dev
```

Now I create Docker image and run there service using docker-compose.

I have no idea where I put yarn prisma migrate deploy command in Dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:17 AS BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "tsconfig.json", "./"]
COPY ["./prisma/schema.prisma", "./prisma/"]
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn prisma generate
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
#RUN yarn install --production
RUN yarn autoclean --force

FROM node:17-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "node", "dist/server.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use docker for development, and I have done that using the `CMD` on my `Dockerfile`, here you go my configuration:

```
FROM node:16.5.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . .
RUN npm i
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.5.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
CMD /wait && cd selling-point-db && npm i && npx prisma migrate dev && npx prisma db seed && cd .. && npm run start:dev
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is working. Thanks you so much for your Dockerfile.

Comment: It was a pleasure :)